# About Bitwise operator

Tags: c

```
if((x & 1) == 0)
    printf("EVEN!\n");
else
    printf("ODD!\n");
```

why `X&1` will always gives `1` when number is odd.. I mean what is happening in memory during this operation can any one explain it ?

Comment: What part don't you understand? Have you tried writing the binary codes yourself and &-ing the numbers? Wikipedia has a [good entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) as well.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in your C book, any online-tutorial, Wikipedia, etc.?

Comment: `(x & 1)` isolates the least significant bit.  Each bit corresponds to a power of two in the same way that each digit of a decimal number corresponds to a power of ten -- and the only integer power of two that is odd is 2^0, for the low bit.  The other bits have no effect on odd/even, since no matter how many even numbers you add together the result is still even... but one more than any even number (same number with 2^0 added in) will be odd.

Comment: This would be why you should learn binary numbers _before_ learning programming.

Answer (score 0):

Every odd number in binary has the lowest order bit set. And `X & 1` is always testing that bit. Hence that check is always true.

If you don't see why the first statement is true then just convert a few decimal numbers to binary and it should be clear.

```
1 == 00000001b
3 == 00000011b
5 == 00000101b
7 == 00000111b
etc
```

Then just to be sure, do the same for a few even numbers to verify that the lowest order bit is always 0:

```
2 == 00000010b
4 == 00000100b
6 == 00000110b
8 == 00001000b
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of binary number. Every binary number is the set of the 2 to the power of some number. If you are looking for the 4 bit number, then only odd number is 1(2 to the power of 0). If you are looking for number for example 12 it is on binary representation 1100. When you put the mask of 1 it looks like this

```
    1100
   &0001
    0000
```

if you pick a odd number for example 3, you have
 
    `0011
   &0001
    0001`
As you can see only last digit of binary number is odd and 1 is 00000001.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what `sizeof(int)` on a platform, the number `1` represented by all  the bits set to `0` except the least significant bit, which is set to `1`. Let's the take the most common representation -- a 32 bit number. On such a platform, `1` is:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
```

If you perform a bitwise AND operation of any other number with `1`, all the bits except the least significant bit will always be `0`. The only time the least significant bit of the result will be `1` is when the least significant bit of the other number is also `1`.

Those numbers are:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001, which is 1
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011, which is 3
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101, which is 5
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111, which is 7
```

and so on. As you can see from the pattern, the least significant bits of all the odd numbers are `1`. The least significant bit of all the even numbers are `0`. Hence,

```
x & 1 is 1 for all odd values of x
x & 1 is 0 for all even values of x
```

Comment: binary 111 is not 5, it's 7... and binary 1111 is 15.  5 in binary would be 101.